I need to embed a power bi report in a webpage using iFrame
I am aware of the options publish to web and embed securely which generates code and gives it to us, but publish to web comes with a concern that data is now available to all the users on the internet and embed securely will cost me a licence is there a way to code my way out of both these options and integrate it with my webpage, also my power bi page requires a windows authentication , I just want to know if there's a way to do it and how it can be done without publish to web or embed securely.
I have tried setting up a proxy server but I got an error saying "refused to display in a frame because it is set 'X-Frame_Options' to "SameOrigin", I have access to the power bi server to there in web.config I added X-Frame=Option to allowALL, but that did not work to.
